# Symplectic or Poisson geometry first?

Tags: book-recommendation, advice

I know that symplectic geometry and Poisson geometry are strictly connected and I also know that historically symplectic geometry came first.

I know very very little about this two subbranches of differential geometry but Poisson geometry intrigues me more because of it uses Lie groupoids and algebroids.

Is it advisable to study Poisson geometry without knowing symplectic geometry or am I making a mistake?

Moreove if I decide to study Poisson geometry, is “Lectures on Poisson Geometry” (Crainic, Fernandes, Marcut) a good fit?

I already have a pretty solid understanding of basic differential geometry and riemannian geometry (and I also have a good understanding of Lie groups and Lie algebras).

Comment: My 2 cents: it's important to know basic symplectic geometry, but you can learn it on the way. The book is by some of the main experts in the field; it may be difficult at places, but overall it looks like a good book for beginners, especially given your interest in groupoids.